# CCTV Problems - 2 same cameras and different configuration

Tags: web, configuration, hikvision

Hi I am having an issue with my CCTV cameras.
I have 2 analog camera same model (dahua HDCVI DH-HAC-B1A11P) and my DVR is Hikvision DS-7104HGHI-K1.

Mi issue is that the configuration of my cameras are different and the resolution of one of the camera is very bad quality

here are some pics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Xfs9.jpg)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x40ez.jpg)

I tried updating the firmware of my DVR